# find with conditions on assosiated models only

Tags: cakephp

I am using containable behaviour in cake 2.4. I have 2 tables - pages and pages_translated. Pages hasMany pages_translated.

Since page can be in different language, pages table has numbers only (id, stats, image, ect). pages_translated has its own id, page_id, name, slug, locale, description ect.

My issue is that I only have data that can be uniquely selected from pages_translated( combination of slug and locale). If I were to write a separate query to select page_id form pages_translated by specyfying slug and locale, that would give me 1 result. I would then search by that Page_id in pages table and get one result again. I would like to achieve that in 1 query. Is that even possible? Whenever I put 1 query in cake without specyfying condition on the main table, it always says:

```
.... FROM pages_translated WHERE pages_translated .locale = eng AND         
      pages_translated.slug = 'www.mypage.com' AND pages_translated.page_id` = (1)
```

That last part where page_id = 1 breaks everything but I guess cake puts it there to make sure only 1 row is selected. How can I instruct it so it does not write that last statement?

Comment: In your PagesTranslated model have you set a belongsTo relationship with your Page model?  And please post your controller code to show us how you have written your find.

Comment: Yes I did declare belongsTo assosiation. In my controller Im just doing this:
     $this->Page->find('first', array('contain' => array('Languages'=>       array('conditions'=> array('Languages.locale' => 'eng', 'Languages.slug' => 'www.mypage.com'),),)));